# AWS Terraform - attach multiple ip addresses as targets

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the map variable below to be used as targets for my Target Group based on the environment and app region.

```
# Target Group IP List
variable "ip_list" {
  type = map(map(list(string)))
  description = "AWS Target Group IP List"
  default = {
    "sqa" = {
      "sea" = ["ip1","ip2","ip3"]
      "anz" = ["ip1","ip2","ip3"]
    },
    "uat" = {
      "sea" = ["ip4","ip5","ip6"]
      "anz" = ["ip7","ip8","ip9"]
    },
    "prod" = {
      "sea" = ["ip4","ip5","ip6"]
      "anz" = ["ip7","ip8","ip9"]
    }
  }
}
```

In order to determine the IP list from the given map, I have a local variable to do a lookup.

```
locals {
    tgset = lookup(lookup(var.ip_list,var.environment),var.app_region)
}
```

Now, here's the TG attachment that, supposedly, will do a for_each iteration on the string list and add each IP address as the **target.id**.

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "tg_main_ip" {
    provider = aws.main
    for_each = toset(local.tgset)
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.tg[tg_name_main].arn
    target.id = each.value
}
```

However, when I run my code, below is the error I get.

```
An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use
the equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.
```

I've seen solutions on how to attach multiple targets based on their resource blocks but not from a map. Any idea how to sort this out?

AWS Terraform Target Group

Comment: What specific line of code is Terraform telling you has the error?

Comment: in this part.

│   on main.tf line 29, in resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "tg_main_ip":
│   29:     target.id = each.value

Answer (score 0):

There is no `target.id`, as per [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_target_group_attachment), it should be `target_id`.